# Duplicate title and deleted page

Tags: google-search-console, duplicate-content

In Search Console → HTML Improvements I have 11 duplicate meta descriptions and 7 duplicate title tags. In all the cases, it is generated by one page that now does not exist anymore. Some were errors in a link or pages created by mistake.

This is what I did months ago:

- I redirected in the .htaccess with a 301, from the page that does not exist to the new page. I have checked that the redirection works.
- I made a search and I am sure that I have no internal link that points to the old page.

I did that on May 2016 and I still have the same errors on August 2016. As that pages do not exist, should I delete that redirection in the .htaccess? Is there anything else that I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to remove 301 redirect, if the content is relevant.

There are too many webpages out there, and Google can't notify them in search console at a same time. So, I suggest either wait for a long time or just forgot that error message, since you already fix it.

I also liked to mention another thing. Many days ago I have also get HTML improvement messages in my seach console. One is having sort title for homepage and second is duplicate title tag for one of my blog post, So I just correct them, and after few weeks the first error was gone, because it is homepage and Google often crawl it, while second error take some time to gone.